# \currentitle in memoir class header prints next section title

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I have a weird problem with the memoir class.

I'm using it to typeset a book of short stories. I have the headers set up so that the page numbers are printed on the outer side. On the left-hand page, the book title is printed right-justified; on the right-hand page the title of the current story appears on the left. As far as I know, this is fairly usual. It looks like this:

Page number --- Book title | Story title --- Page number

The book title is inserted statically, i.e. not using any kind of command like \title. To get the story title I use \currenttitle thus:

```
\makeoddhead{headings}{\emph{\MakeUppercase{\currenttitle}}}{}{\thepage}
```

This all works fine *except* when a story finishes at the bottom of a right-hand page. Instead of printing that story's title in the header of that page, memoir uses the title of the story that begins overleaf!

I've not posted a minimal example, as the error obviously only occurs when you have the 'right' amount of text to fill up a few pages, but it is a reproducible error in the sense that it happens three times in this document with 30 stories in it.

Instead of a minimal example, here's the preamble:

```
\documentclass[postvopaper,twoside,10pt]{memoir}
\raggedbottom

\usepackage{fontspec} % Font selection for XeLaTeX; see fontspec.pdf for documentation
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} % to support TeX conventions like ``\Emdash*''
\usepackage{xunicode} % Unicode support for LaTeX character names (accents, European chars, etc)
\usepackage{xltxtra} % Extra customizations for XeLaTeX
\usepackage{ellipsis}


\setmainfont{Lido STF} % set the main body font (\textrm)
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage{enumitem}
  \setlist[description{style=multiline,labelwidth=60pt,leftmargin=70pt%,itemindent=\dimexpr-20pt-\labelsep\relax
}

\usepackage{extdash}

% reduce size of footnote marker
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\hbox{\textsuperscript{\tiny{\@thefnmark}}}}
\makeatother

%%% PAGE LAYOUT 

\setlrmarginsandblock{0.15\paperwidth}{*}{1} % Left and right margin
\setulmarginsandblock{0.2\paperwidth}{*}{1}  % Upper and lower margin
    \sloppybottom
\checkandfixthelayout

%%-----------

\title{The Complete Annotated Reginald Stories}
\author{Saki}
\date{}

\makeevenhead{headings}{\thepage}{}{\emph{Complete Annotated Reginald Stories}}
\makeoddhead{headings}{\emph{\MakeUppercase{\currenttitle}}}{}{\thepage}
\pagestyle{headings}
```

Comment: Please post a full minimal example, that makes it a lot easier to help you when we do not have to add anything to see the problem. IMO you're doing this wrong. You need to use `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` in order to access the latest sectonal title. These are usually specified using  `\makepsmarks`, done right the `\MakeUppercase` will be build in as it isn't always that good as handling data stored in a macro.

Comment: BTW: the `kantlipsum` package and its `\kant` macro is very handy to provide sample text

Comment: I deliberately didn't give a minimal example, as the nature of the problem meant I would have had to fiddle about trying to get exactly the right amount of dummy text so that a section finished at the bottom of a page. (Otherwise the error won't occur.) Most lorem ipsum packages I know don't offer such a fine level of control. On the plus side, I changed \currenttitle to \rightmark and now it works, so thanks for your help!

Comment: Just see preparing an MWE as payment for peoples help.

Comment: :-) Can you change your first comment to an answer so that I can mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the asynchronous nature of the headers and footers, `\currenttitle` is not a good choice for the header. More traditionally `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` are used.

Also note that these marks  are uppercase in `memoir` by default.

If interested you can have a look at the headings style code in the memoir sources, `\makepsmarks` and how it is used might be interesting.

There is also an article about memoir pagestyles in the PracTeX Journal, http://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-2/madsen/